# PHP: Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object

Tags: php, database, global, wordpress

I get an error from using the function below: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object.
Please help!

```
<?php 

$hostname = "dd";
$username = "cc";
$password = "aa";
$dbName = "bb";
MYSQL_CONNECT($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE("Unable to connect to database");
@mysql_select_db("$dbName") or die( "Unable to select database");

subscribe($email, $firstname, $lastname, $company);

function subscribe($email, $first, $last, $company)
{
             global $wpdb;  
             $wpdb -> insert('aca11052015_subscribers', array(
            'First Name' => $first,
            'Last Name' => $last,
            'Company' => $company,
            'Email' => $email,
            'Date' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
        ));    
}
```

Comment: So im guessing this is a wordpress theme/plugin? Where is this code saved and how is it called?

Comment: The errors means that $wpdb isn't an object. It probably didn't get initialized correctly, perhaps as a result of a bad credentials for the database connection. Or maybe the database server is down.

Comment: Steve, I am currently creating a php template that takes ajax posts and insert them into our database.

Comment: Alex, I think we have a proper database connection. I'm not sure if I'm initializing it correctly...

Comment: The $wpdb global has not been initiated as you are running ajax - within the file that has that code if you require_once('wp-load.php'); with the correct path to that file (it should be in the root of your site) things should start working

Comment: Thanks Simon it worked!

Comment: Great stuff :) I just added a proper answer, if you could mark that as correct that would be great thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $wpdb global has not been initiated as you are running via ajax and calling that file independently.

Within the file that has that code if you add:

```
require_once('wp-load.php');
```

Make sure that it points to the correct path to that file (it should be in the root of your site) things should start working.